# How can I change Vim's start or intro screen text? (Windows)

Tags: vim

When I start vim I always see this:

```
              VIM - Vi IMproved

           version 7.4.580
       by Bram Moolenaar et al.
  Vim is open source and freely distributable
      Become a registered Vim user!
  type  :help register<Enter>   for information
  type  :q<Enter>               to exit
  type  :help<Enter>  or  <F1>  for on-line help
  type  :help version7<Enter>   for version info
```

Is there some way to modify this text to my own desire?

Comment: Try this https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/627/how-can-i-change-vims-start-or-intro-screen

Comment: I read this comment but did not understand what to do? could you please guide me as I literally just joined vim a week ago.

Comment: @ShaharyarAhmed. Answers in Hoppo's link recommend you to install vim plugin "startify". If you want get all power of Vim, plugins are good option. To use them, you have need plugin manager. The most easy I know is "pathogen": https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen. Install it with instruction and then install "startify".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `.vimrc`, credit for this goes to [Martin Tournoij](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/51/martin-tournoij), check his [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/715/26507) to know more about it.

```
fun! Start()
    " Don't run if: we have commandline arguments, we don't have an empty
    " buffer, if we've not invoked as vim or gvim, or if we'e start in insert mode
    if argc() || line2byte('$') != -1 || v:progname !~? '^[-gmnq]\=vim\=x\=\%[\.exe]$' || &insertmode
        return
    endif

    " Start a new buffer ...
    enew

    " ... and set some options for it
    setlocal
        \ bufhidden=wipe
        \ buftype=nofile
        \ nobuflisted
        \ nocursorcolumn
        \ nocursorline
        \ nolist
        \ nonumber
        \ noswapfile
        \ norelativenumber

    " Now we can just write to the buffer, whatever you want.
    call append('$', "This is a new file in vim ")

    " No modifications to this buffer
    setlocal nomodifiable nomodified

    " When we go to insert mode start a new buffer, and start insert
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> e :enew<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> i :enew <bar> startinsert<CR>
    nnoremap <buffer><silent> o :enew <bar> startinsert<CR>
endfun

" Run after "doing all the startup stuff"
autocmd VimEnter * call Start()
```

The following line is important to show any text:

```
call append('$', "This is a new file in vim ")
```

Just modify the text between the quotes to whatever text you want, for example if want to show `This is the text I want to show`, do the following:

```
call append('$', "This is the text I want to show")
```

You can also add multiple line, like so:

```
call append('$', "This is the text I want to show")
call append('$', "Another line to show when you start a new vim instance")
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply but I was able to get it to work! Thanks